# I need a button to clear cells in a google spreadsheet

Tags: button, google-sheets

Im making a tool for myself with Google Spreadsheets, and as part of that tool I would like to have a button that clears a specific set of cells.  As I understand it, I need to insert a drawing, and then assign a script to that drawing.  Trouble is, I dont know the first thing about writing my own so, im here looking for help!

The end goal of this would be for me to have a drawing with a script attached to it that would, when activated, clear the data (make them blank, but leave the color) from cells B7-G7.

Any help you guys could offer would be fantastic!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Such script is very simple, you should look at the [tutorials](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles.html) to learn how to do it yourself.

Anyway, here it is:

```
function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('B7:G7').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ^.^  I was trying to teach myself, but I just honestly dont get programming.
I have the script set up in the editor, and it works just fine.  BUT, I cant seem to get it to assign to one of the buttons that I drew.  Im clicking the button, selecting "assign Script" and then typing the name of the script into the box that comes up.  When I hit ok, and then click the button with the script assigned, I get an error that says "Script function CAC could not be found"  CAC is the name of the script.

Comment: You should write the function name, not the script name. In my example `clearRange`

Comment: *facepalm*  Thank you so much guys.  Im a total noob here.  One more question, and then all is right with the world.  How do I go about setting up different buttons to clear different ranges?  For example, I now have my button set to clear B7 to G7 thanks to you awesome people, but I need another now to clear B13-G13.  I made a second script, but they are function named "clearRange"

Comment: I don't need to create a second "script". Just another function in the same script. Copy this function, change the range to the desired one, and rename the function to something like clearRange2.

Answer (score 11):

To add a custom menu to your Google spreadsheet, that when clicked, will list all your functions. See the code below

```js
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menubuttons = [ {name: "Clear B7-G7", functionName: "clearRange1"},
                  {name: "Clear B13-G13", functionName: "clearRange2"}];
    ss.addMenu("Custom", menubuttons);
} // note you also have to have functions called clearRange1 and clearRange2 as list below
```

```js
function clearRange1() { //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('B7:G7').clearContent();
}
```

```js
function clearRange2() { //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('B13:G13').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Custom menus! Thank you!