# Google Spreadsheets: Button to add B to A and then clear B

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Helpful answer, but not exactly what I'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268570/i-need-a-button-to-clear-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

The above answer gives part of the script I'm looking for. I'd like to add another step (or two) but have no idea how.

```
Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
```

I have a column of numbers, and would like to add numbers from another. The part I can't figure out is how to clear the cells after the numbers have been added to the first column.

```
Like this:

A <---B
1 <---2 
2 <---5 
3 <---24
```

On the click of a button, I'd like the numbers from B to be added to A and then B cleared. Column A would become 3, 7, 27, and the cells in Column B would become blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var tRange = sheet.getRange('A1:A3');
  var tValues = tRange.getValues();
  var sRange = sheet.getRange('B1:B3');
  var sValues = sRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < tValues.length; i++) {
    tValues[i][0] += sValues[i][0];
  }
  tRange.setValues(tValues);
  sRange.clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a button to your spreadsheet menu to execute AdmaL's code example above using this code

```js
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menubutton = [ {name: "Add Range", functionName: "addRange"}]; //"addRange" is the name of the function submitted by AdamL Above //This would also need to be included as a function in your script as the function to call when you click the "Custom" menu button
    ss.addMenu("Custom", menubutton);
}
```