# Google Sheets blank for new visitors?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create an ordinary Google Sheets spreadsheet available to any user, with row/column headers, users enter their numerical data in columns in an editable area (B2:C8), and at the bottom of the columns there are several cells with formulas that use the numerical values entered by users to calculate a value. I am having two problems:

- one formulas require the sum of differences between two columns [(C2-B2)+(C3-B3)+C4-B4)…] and this sum must be divided by 7. I could not find a way to implement this calculation in one cell;
- if the sheet is accessed by an user the editable area should be blank so that the user enters his data without having to erase first the data entered by a previous user.

How can I make the editable area of the sheet blank for a visitor?

Comment: can you please explain more about your issue with code or errors.

Comment: Here is the sheet I am working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/edit#gid=0

- range B2:H8 should be blank (no numbers in the cells) when somebody visits the sheet. I do not know how to do it!
- for the second issue I have to sum up the difference between two columns, =SUM(C2-B2)+(C3-B3)+(C4-B4)+(C5-B5)+(C6:B6)+(C7-B7)+(C8-B8), then divide the result by 7 (because there are 7 rows) and display the result in one cell. Again, I do not know how to do it!

Thank you!

Comment: @Felix I can see this can be an important spreadsheet. Are you conducting a survey? Do you plan to recover the data from the spreadsheets and aggregate it.

Comment: Tedinoz - Not actually a survey and I do not plan (or know) to recover the data from the spreadsheet. This a spreadsheet that allows people with diabetes on self monitoring of the blood glucose (finger pricking) to calculate some indices to figure out the glycemia variability (and how stable their diabetes is) from their daily glycemia readings (at least seven readings per day).

Comment: @Felix Thank for clarifying the use of the spreadsheet - unfortunately it makes things more complicated. I am concerned about how to distribute your spreadsheet. It looks like you want your spreadsheet to be like a template but this is easier said than done. In addition, the spreadsheet is to be "available to any user" but later you refer to a "visitor" - you haven't defined what you understand by "user/visitor". For example, is a "user" only a person who has their own Google account, or is it anyone who can access the internet to share your spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tedinoz, the spreadsheet should be accessible to anyone who can access the internet. Visitor = any user. Let's assume that we have two different users, each one should be presented with a separate instance of the spreadsheet, so each user could perform his calculations without any interference from the other user. Once the user is done calculating the instances should be killed, since the data is not stored. Google Sheets is probably not the best approach, it should be done with software but that is beyond my abilities.

Comment: @Felix I thought as much. Refer my answer for sharing the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

re:

> I could not find a way to implement this calculation in one cell;

Maybe:

```
=(SUM(C2:C)-SUM(B2:B))/7
```

For example:

[image: SO53315931 example]

Comment: It will return value of 39.57 rather it should be -40.86

Comment: Yes it works now, Do automated scripts will erase cell data, i think so.

Answer (score 1):

I can find solution for Sum and divide logic

```
=SUM(C2-B2,C3-B3,C4-B4,C5-B5,C6-B6,C7-B7,C8-B8)/7
```

Sum is `-286`
after Div by 7 will be `-40.86`

Yes there is a way to make your row clear but not for new visitor but for Time basis.
You can Try Automation script for that,
Read [How do I create an Auto-Clear Script in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269976/how-do-i-create-an-auto-clear-script-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

1)Go to https://script.google.com and then add a New Script
2) Use I checked this Working for me,

```
function myFunction() {
      var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw").getSheetByName("Indici");
      sheetActive.getRange('B2:H2').clearContent();
}
```

3) Goto Run & select Run function and then select clearRange.
4) Goto Edit, Select 'current project triggers'
5) add trigger
6) time driven minutes every 5 minutes run this script automatically.
7) In All your triggers popup windows, select clearRange as the Run function.

Comment: With respect, your answer does not address the issue of making the spreadsheet available to others. First, there is no predictability about the timing of a new user opening the spreadsheet; every 5 minutes may be insufficient. Second, until a user makes a copy of the spreadsheet (however this might be triggered, if at all) any data entry will be promptly erased by the Auto-Clear script. Third, the Auto-Clear script will function ad-infinitum, though it will fail as soon as the spreadsheet obtains a new ID. There is also the matter of how to protect the calculation (and some other) fields.

Comment: Ashish, your solution for sum and divide in the same cell is correct. I double checked it manually and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that the data entry area will be "blank for the next visitor" is an important consideration. The spreadsheet is to be used/accessed freely, anonymously with complete privacy, by an unknown number of people. The users do not necessarily share a common understanding about the sharing of spreadsheets, and some users may or may not immediately understand or comprehend the on-going implications of how to use, access and copy the spreadsheet. Ideally the spreadsheet could be distributed as a "template". But this is not an option for users of the free Google Docs service.

In short, it is unsafe to delegate the process of creating a copy of the spreadsheet. There's also the matter of protecting the questioner's integrity by ensuring that no end-user can ever accidentally access or delete the data of another person. For these reasons, the spreadsheet should never be directly accessed or opened by an end-user.

The solution is let Google create the copy of the spreadsheet. The "normal" shared spreadsheet url ends with `/edit` (even if a user has "View only" access). Manually substitute `/copy` for `/edit` to change the url like this:
Copy url -> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/copy`
Edit url -> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/edit`

When the url is accessed, the end-user will first see this screen. Note that the original document name ("Indici_diabetici") is shown.

---

[image: Google copy document]

---

By clicking "Make a Copy", Google creates a copy of the spreadsheet. The copy has a new ID, the user becomes its "owner" and it is saved in the user's own Drive account.

The original spreadsheet should be shared for "View only" access; this will ensure that if an inquisitive user were to change the url back to `/edit` they would be unable to change or modify the original spreadsheet.

The questioner would most likely include some appropriate explanatory information on the first sheet of the spreadsheet, so the end-user will still have guidance about the purpose and use of the spreadsheet.

To simplify access and avoid confusion, I would suggest that the actual url should be published only as a web link. Something along these lines: [Want a copy of this template?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/copy)

Comment: Tedinoz - thank you for your extensive comment, I modified the URL as you suggested but it redirects me to google login page!

Comment: @Felix The examples in my answer (plain text and the link at the bottom) are both using your own spreadsheets URL. What URL did you come up with?

Comment: When I am legged into my google account the url of the spreadsheet is 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/edit#gid=0

Comment: when I log out either url https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/edit

or

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/copy

sends me to the google login page.

Comment: @Felix This is the correct url: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gp4_TgazhYsZmJWEsRXYtEf2XJAW0sCrsS-o4ZN3oKw/copy`. To access and use the spreadsheet (enter data, save the file, etc), a user needs a Google account. You were logged out, so Google took you to a login page, and then it would have let you make a copy of the sheet. FWIW, "View only" access doesn't require a Google account, but "View only" would be useless in this case.

Comment: got it! Thank you.