# How do I create an auto clear script for Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, scripting

I am attempting to set up my first Google Script, so a complete novice here.
I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets. I'd like to clear all of the data in one of the sheets automatically every day.

I saw a couple of years ago, a user [posted a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269976/how-do-i-create-an-auto-clear-script-in-a-google-spreadsheet) However, I'm trying to run the same script and getting no luck.

The script I'm attempting to run is:

```
function myFunction() {
function clearRange() {
  // replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  // replace 'dhrhrejYOURSHETIDerhe5j54j5j' with your actual sheet ID

  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14jXnD3mCi-BvL8lAindct9InTZgO8CLOaItbPrCfCng").getSheetByName("One");
  sheetActive.getRange('A:Y').clearContent();

}
}
```

The Sheet name and ID is already replaced with mine. The issue is whenever I run the script, nothing changes on my sheet. Any tips on what to do here? Is there an updated script I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `function myFunction() {` and last `}`

This works fine

```
function clearRange() {
  // replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  // replace 'dhrhrejYOURSHETIDerhe5j54j5j' with your actual sheet ID

  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14jXnD3mCi-BvL8lAindct9InTZgO8CLOaItbPrCfCng").getSheetByName("One");
  sheetActive.getRange('A:Y').clearContent();

}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks for helping out a noob. Appreciate it, Mike.