# Google Sheets Script - Move Rows from One Tab to Another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, move

I'm trying to modify the code from the below forum post to help  fit my needs:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

```
function onEdit() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Transfers";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 15; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "yes";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

What this code does is moves a row from one tab to another when a specific value is entered (in the code above, it moves a row from "Transfers" to "Archive" when the word "yes" is entered in column 15 (Column O).

My needs are a little bit different. I cannot have a user moving one row at a time because there may be multiple rows involved and combined together, they will need to meet certain criteria (e.g. do the amounts in all rows balance to 0, is the same account used, etc.).  This I believe is a rudimentary data validation.

Therefore, I tried to make a formula so that if I entered the word yes in cell F8, it populates the word "Send" (used to be "yes", changed for clarity) to column O. If the word yes is entered in cell F8, then every row with the word "Send" should be moved to the Archive Column. The problem is, the above code relied on a function called OnEdit, and populating the rows with the word Send via formula does not trigger the script to run. The above code needs the user to manually enter the correct keyword in order to move the rows over.

Can someone help to modify or rewrite the code so that it looks for a user to manually type in the keyword "yes" in cell F8, and then have it move any row that had the word "Send" populated by a formula in Column O?

The below Google Sheet is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. Additional comments can be found on the "MASTER - DO NOT EDIT" tab.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iajS90qvwEOGVnl2lpDbVtcI532OO8n4NLZEBDUpVzA/edit#gid=398066315

Thanks for looking. If anyone needs additional info, please let me know.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT: I tried out Cooper's code below, and it seems to work. I'm a novice at this, but I've managed to add a few things to make it run onEdit, and to delete the initial trigger word.

An example of this slightly tweaked code running can be found below:

```
function onEdit() {
  archiveRows();
  clearCells();

}

function archiveRows()
{

/*installable trigger rows 10-13 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
 if(!projectTriggerExists()
 {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onOpen()
    .create();
 }//by wrapping the trigger creation like this you don't have to worry about creating unwanted triggers.
*/  

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Transfers'); //sh0 = Transfers tab
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange(); //rg0 = Range of sh0, This is functionally equivalent to creating a Range bounded by A1 and (Range.getLastColumn(), Range.getLastRow()). https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Archive'); //sh1 = Archive tab
  var vals=rg0.getValues(); //Returns the rectangular grid of values for this range. Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column. The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String, depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells will be represented by an empty string in the array. Remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array will be indexed from [0][0]. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues
  for(var i=vals.length-1;i>11;i--) //When deleting rows it is better to start from the bottom otherwise deleted rows will mess up your loop indexing
  {
    if(vals[i][14]=='SEND') //If column 14 in the range has the word 'SEND' then run the next lines of code. 14 is column O. Column 0 is 15, but see note above regarding JavaScript array being indexed from [0][0]
    {
      sh1.appendRow(vals[i]);
      sh0.deleteRow(i+1);//indexes start at zero but rows start at one
    }

  }

}
//This could be accomplished with SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().clear();
function clearCells()
{
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268570/i-need-a-button-to-clear-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('A1:A1').clearContent()
}

function projectTriggerExists(functionName)
{
  if(functionName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var funcExists=false;
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      var trigger=allTriggers[i];
      if(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()==functionName)
      {
        funcExists=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return funcExists;
}
```

The nature of the spreadsheet is that I will need to duplicate the "Transfers" tab in the original post a dozen times so that it can be used by multiple people at once (data being entered in by the user essentially over 12 "forms"). All the data put into these dozen "Transfers" tabs should rout to the same "Archive" tab. However, I'd also like to build in a rudimentary routing system, so that instead of having everything rout to one tab, different code words send the lines to different "Archive" tabs. For instance, "OK+Send+Staff1" sends the line to a tab called Staff1Archive, "OK+Send+Staff2"  sends to a tab called Staff2Archive,  "OK+Send+Staff3"  sends to a tab called Staff3Archive, etc.

Can anyone help with this code as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it for you.

```
function archiveRows()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Transfers');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Archive');
  var vals=rg0.getValues();
  for(var i=vals.length-1;i>11;i--)
  {
    if(vals[i][14]=='SEND')
    {
      sh1.appendRow(vals[i]);
      sh0.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thank you for your help! I've been researching how to tweak the original code for months now but kept running into roadblocks. I've added in some additional background info (scope creep, sorry) about what I'm trying to do. Would you be able to take a look and provide further guidance if possible? I would appreciate it. If not, thank you so much for your time! I'm a novice at this, so I appreciate all the help I can get.