# Require fix to script app to move an array from one google sheet to another on a trigger. either through a button or cell input

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to create a script that will allow the following steps to occur
1. I input property survey data on Sheet "Inputs" in Array(B4:H4) 
2. On Cell (F13) being between 98%-102%, the option (button or cell highlighted(I7)) to ADD to target sheet appears or becomes active
3. on pressing the cell or button data is moved to sheet "New Base(C5:I5)"
4. Data in target Array is deleted
5. On the repeat of the above cycle for new paddocks, data adds below already moved data on Sheet "New Base"

So far I have used a mash-up of different scripts I have found online. I've included the references in them.

My apologies if I've used incorrect terminology. The link to the sheet is below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KAXtTKijPjhH70pNe3RHUl5R6UwaJNRVBnqgFx4mmcw/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be much appreciated for one confused Newby.

```js
function onEdit() {
  archiveRows();
  clearCells();

}

function archiveRows()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Inputs');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('New Base');
  var vals=rg0.getValues();
  for(var i=vals.length-1;i>11;i--)
  {
    if(vals[i][9]=='ADD')
    {
      sh1.appendRow(vals[i]);
      sh0.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
}
//This could be accomplished with SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().clear();
function clearCells('B4:H4')
{
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268570/i-need-a-button-to-clear-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Inputs');;
  ss.getRange('B4:H4').clearContent('B4:H4')
}

function projectTriggerExists(functionName)
{
  if(functionName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var funcExists=false;
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      var trigger=allTriggers[i];
      if(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()==functionName)
      {
        funcExists=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return funcExists;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If I understood correctly, you input some values in `B4:H4`, and if the value in `F13` is between 98%-102%, the user can click on `I7` to add those values to "New Base" and clears them from `B4:H4`. I'm not sure if I understood step 5. Does it move to the rows below B4:H4?. I think it would be better to use a [dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title), as it would be more clear. May I ask what is your current issue with your code?

Comment: Hey Jescanellas thanks for looking at my issue, yes that's correct for 1-4. step 5 is 1-4 repeated with the next lot of values being transfered and added on "New Base" below already inputed data. Currently data is not appearing in the new base sheet and values in all sheets are clearing. last correction I made now the headings in new base are clearing

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What do you think of implementing this with [dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)? I think it would be more user friendly, also without the limitations of the Sheet to implement buttons.

Comment: Hi Jescanellas, sorry fo the late reply. Do you mean to use a dialog box to explain the requirements clearly or as a "button" to execute the input?